# How to write custom provider for enum objects?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, enums, annotations, guice

I am using Google Guice 4.1.0 for writing the provider. But while Injecting the object of enum getting error (Error in custom provider, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot reflectively create enum objects)

I tried removing the constructor from enum with @Inject annotation and adding @NoArgsConstructors and @AllArgsConstructors but getting error that enum must have either one constructor with @Inject annotation or one and only one constructor without parameter.

My enum :

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public enum IngestionMode {
    HAZELCAST(HazelcastMapCache.class),
    NEW_INGESTION(IngestionDataStoreCache.class);

    @Inject
    IngestionMode(){
        cacheTypeClass = HazelcastMapCache.class;
    }

    public Class cacheTypeClass;
}
```

Corresponding Provider:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public IngestionMode getIngestionOperatingMode() {
        return IngestionMode.HAZELCAST;
}
```

HazelcastMapCache and IngestionDataStoreCache are Normal Java classes.

Using following enum causing error "enum must have either one constructor with @Inject annotation or one and only one constructor without parameter."

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
public enum IngestionMode {
    HAZELCAST(HazelcastMapCache.class),
    NEW_INGESTION(IngestionDataStoreCache.class);

    private final Class cacheTypeClass;
}
```

What can be possible workaround for this?

Comment: Are you trying to create HAZLECAST, NEW_INGESTION using Guice in your IngestionMode enum?

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this in your `Module`:

```java
@Override protected void configure() {
  bind(IngestionMode.class).toInstance(IngestionMode.HAZELCAST);
}
```